# Is there any way to integrate my Facebook Messenger bot with an ionic app?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have made a facebook messenger bot using node.js and hosted on heroku. How can I integrate the bot with my ionic app, so that the bot runs on the app and not on facebook messenger. I am new to this, so please help me out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The facebook messenger platform is for building bots that run on Facebook messenger and use the native features of facebook messenger and not on your website/app. Period.

But there are a couple of things you can do to integrate your website and your bot and make them work more tightly together.

1. Checkbox Plugin : Signup user for your messenger bot directly from your website/app.
2. Send to Messenger : Authenticate a user from your website/app
3. Message us : i.e. you can even begin a messenger conversation with your user from your website/app.

Read more about these possibilities [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference).